# Is there any moral dilemma/situation clearly showing the usefulness of virtue ethics?

Tags: ethics, virtue-ethics

I have to study a case where I take any moral dilemma or situation I want to and apply virtue ethics on it but I can't really seem to find anything.

Comment: Virtue ethics IEP. https://www.iep.utm.edu/virtue/ Also, go to your college/university library and become familiar with it. Don't do a computer search of the catalog. Go to the stacks under ethics, philosophy. Also check the reference section of your library.

Comment: If you begin to get familiar with your library in a broad way, it can be helpful in all your subjects.

Comment: We discourage one-line questions that simply quote HW assignments. You have to describe the context of the course they came up in and your own attempts to answer them. General information on virtue ethics can be found in online encyclopedias, like IEP above or [SEP](https://plato.stanford.edu/entries/ethics-virtue/).